# How can I create a special character shortcut for an IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I would like to attach the shortcut `ctrl + [` to an action in an IntelliJ plugin I'm writing.

For `ctrl` plus any letter, this works. However, for a square bracket, this doesn't seem to work. I have tried escpaing using `\[`.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
<action id="DoTheThingAction" class="DoTheThingAction" text="Do It" description="Does The Thing">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl \[" keymap="$default" />
</action>
```

While this works:

```
<action id="DoTheThingAction" class="DoTheThingAction" text="Do It" description="Does The Thing">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl w" keymap="$default" />
</action>
```

Do I need to do anything special to create a shortcut for a special character like "["?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `[` or `\[` directly. You need to use `OPEN_BRACKET`.

For example, this works:

```java
<action id="DoTheThingAction" class="DoTheThingAction" text="Do It" description="Does The Thing">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl OPEN_BRACKET" keymap="$default" />
</action>
```